# Metric on $\mathbb{R}$ that agrees with the usual topology

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

In Munkres topology there is an exercise that asks us to prove the following

> Let $X$ be a metrizable space. Show that the following are equivalent.
>   (i) X is bounded under every metric that gives the topology of X.
>   (ii) Every continuous function $\phi: X \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is bounded.
>   (iii) X is limit point compact.

Since the function $f:(-1,1) \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ given by $f(x) = \tan(\frac{\pi}{2} x)$ is unbounded and continuous, that must mean there is a metric on $(-1,1)$ that generates the same topology as the usual topology, but under which $(-1,1)$ is unbounded. Can anyone tell me what metric this is?

Comment: The $f(x)$ you defined is not defined on $(-1,1)$. You probably want $f(x)=\tan \frac{\pi}{2}x$.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews yes that is what I meant. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just follow through the definition. Taking $f(x)=\tan(\pi x/2)$
(which I'm sure is what you intended) then
$$d(x,y)=|f(x)-f(y)|=|\tan(\pi x/2)-\tan(\pi y/2)|.$$

Comment: To say that it agrees with the usual topology you can use the fact that your $f$ is a homeomorphism.

Comment: @NarukiMasuda Exactly, $f$ is a bijection from $(-1,1)$ to $\Bbb R$, so we are just defining the metric to make it an isometry.